# Incompatible shape error when trying to fit my model

Tags: keras, tensorflow, dataset, cnn

I am using keras to make a CNN model. I have a dataset of images which consists of training and validation tfrecord files, the images in the tfrecords are grayscale. I load in the my 2 datasets by following the code from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/philculliton/a-simple-tf-2-1-notebook/notebook) kaggle notebook

```py
def decode_image(image_data):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data, channels=1)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0  # convert image to floats in [0, 1] range
    image = tf.reshape(image, [75,75,1]) # explicit size needed for TPU
    return image

def read_labeled_tfrecord(example):
    LABELED_TFREC_FORMAT = {
        # tf.string means bytestring
        'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'channels': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "label": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'class': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "raw_img": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, LABELED_TFREC_FORMAT)
    image = decode_image(example['raw_img'])
    label = tf.cast(example['class'], tf.int32)
    return image, label # returns a dataset of (image, label) pairs

def load_dataset(filenames, ordered=False):
    # Read from TFRecords. For optimal performance, reading from multiple files at once and
    # disregarding data order. Order does not matter since we will be shuffling the data anyway.

    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    if not ordered:
        ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False # disable order, increase speed

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTO) # automatically interleaves reads from multiple files
    dataset = dataset.with_options(ignore_order) # uses data as soon as it streams in, rather than in its original order
    dataset = dataset.map(read_labeled_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    # returns a dataset of (image, label) pairs 
    return dataset

def get_training_dataset():
    dataset = load_dataset(tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_DS_PATH + '/Data/train/*.tfrec'))
    dataset = dataset.repeat() # the training dataset must repeat for several epochs
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
    return dataset

def get_validation_dataset():
    dataset = load_dataset(tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_DS_PATH + '/Data/valid*.tfrec'), ordered=False)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
    return dataset

training_dataset = get_training_dataset()
validation_dataset = get_validation_dataset()
```

After loading my data, I define a model and fit it like so:

```py
model = Sequential([
        Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
               padding='valid', input_shape=[75,75,1]),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
        Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(units=585, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
    training_dataset, 
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, 
    epochs=EPOCHS, 
    validation_data=validation_dataset
)
```

But when I try to run my code, I am faced with the following error  `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 585) are incompatible`

How can I solve this issue?